# sql select rows with time range

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

Have a table scheme that look as :

```
events{id int, date date, begin time, end time, title varchar)
```

and want to retrieve rows from a web user form, by example : 11:00 (i'm french so use 24h format)

So, if i have in the table the following rows :

```
1 | 2016-03-29 | 11:15 | 12:00
2 | 2016-03-29 | 09:45 | 11:15
3 | 2016-03-29 | 10:45 | 13:00
4 | 2016-03-29 | 12:45 | 14:45
```

I would like to be able to count, or retrieve rows have events that have 11:00 in the range :

```
2 | 2016-03-29 | 09:45 | 11:15
3 | 2016-03-29 | 10:45 | 13:00
```

Note : i use PostgreSQL but want to respect SQL normalization to achieve...

Thanks

Comment: Did you want to retrieve the rows who's begin and end time is in between 11:00 to 11:59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Between` operator

Try this

```
select * 
from yourtable 
where '11:00' between "begin" and "end"
```

Comment: My bad, noticed only the tag he made